# Python 3.2.1: TypeError, Number of Arguments, Etc

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

I have searched for the problem I am having, but have seen different variations of it that don't help me much (I am fairly new to Python; taking it as part of an introduction to programming at a university).

The Problem: I keep getting a TypeError talking about the number of arguments, but I (with my so far limited knowledge of Python) do not see what is wrong.

I have the following functions:

```
def Grid():
borderSet = 20
spaceSize = 50
totalSpaces = 10

boardX = borderSet + (totalSpaces * spaceSize) + (10 * borderSet)
boardY = borderSet + (totalSpaces * spaceSize) + borderSet

board = GraphWin("Hunt the Wumpus", boardX, boardY)

for r in range(totalSpaces):
    for c in range(totalSpaces):
        gridTile = Rectangle(Point(borderSet+ r*spaceSize, borderSet+c*spaceSize), Point(borderSet+(r+1)*spaceSize, borderSet+(c+1)*spaceSize))
        gridTile.setWidth(2)
        gridTile.draw(board)
        gridTileText = Text(Point(((gridTile.getP1().getX() + gridTile.getP2().getX()) / 2), ((gridTile.getP1().getY() + gridTile.getP2().getY()) / 2)), False)
        gridTileText.draw(board)

ctr = DrawCharacter(borderSet, spaceSize)
ctr.draw(board)

a, w, p, t = ChooseDifficulty(boardX, boardY)

Text(Point(boardX - (6 * borderSet), 15 * borderSet), ("Number of arrows:", a)).draw(board)
Text(Point(boardX - (6 * borderSet), 16 * borderSet), ("Number of wumpii:", w)).draw(board)
Text(Point(boardX - (6 * borderSet), 17 * borderSet), ("Number of pits:", p)).draw(board)
Text(Point(boardX - (6 * borderSet), 18 * borderSet), ("Number of treasures:", t)).draw(board)

gW, gWT, gE, gET = Controls(boardX, boardY, borderSet)
gW.draw(board)
gWT.draw(board)
gE.draw(board)
gET.draw(board)
#gN.draw(board)
#gNT.draw(board)
#gS.draw(board)
#gST.draw(board)

click = board.getMouse()

#moveN = rectIntersect(gN, click)
#moveS = rectIntersect(gS, click)
moveE = rectIntersect(gE, click)
moveW = rectIntersect(gW, click)

board.getMouse()

Text(Point(boardX / 2, boardY / 2), (moveE, moveW)).draw(board)

board.getMouse()

ch = MoveCharacter(ctr, moveE, moveW)
ch.draw(board)

board.getMouse()
board.close()

return boardX, boardY
```

and

```
def Controls(bX, bY, bS):
    wP = [Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 5, bS + 80), Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 105, bS + 120)]
    eP = [Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 120, bS + 80), Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 220, bS + 120)]

    goWest = Rectangle(wP)
    goWestText = Text(Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 55, bS + 100), "Turn Left")
    goWestText.setStyle("bold")
    goWest.setFill(color_rgb(190, 30, 10))
    goWestText.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))

    goEast = Rectangle(eP)
    goEastText = Text(Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 145, bS + 100), "Turn Right")
    goEastText.setStyle("bold")
    goEast.setFill(color_rgb(10, 190, 30))

    return goWest, goWestText, goEast, goEastText
```

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    Grid()
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 29, in Grid
    gW, gWT, gE, gET = Controls(boardX, boardY, borderSet)
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 10, in Controls
    goWest = Rectangle(wP)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, your code seems rather Java-like. Python code is often more compact. Not a big deal, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell because you've provided so much code, but I believe what's going on is this:

```
wP = [Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 5, bS + 80), Point(bX - (10 * bS) + 105, bS + 120)]
```

This makes `wP` a list of two elements. Even though it contains two things, it's still a single object.

```
goWest = Rectangle(wP)
```

I'm guessing that the `Rectangle` constructor is supposed to be passed two points as arguments. Along with the implicit `self` parameter that always refers to the object itself, that makes a total of 3 arguments. Python is complaining that it's only seeing two parameters passed, namely the implicit `self` and your list `wP`.

If this is in fact the problem, one way to fix this would be

```
goWest = Rectangle(wP[0], wP[1])
```

A slightly more advanced way would be

```
goWest = Rectangle(*wP)
```

The `*` (argument unpacking) operator basically automates the process of expanding the list elements into individual arguments. `f(*args)` is equivalent to

```
f(args[0], args[1], args[2], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But I'm just curious if you could tell me exactly the reason behind how the "*wP", but not the "wP" works (I'm sorry if you've already done that in your answer; again, I'm fairly new at Python)?

Comment: That last bit: "The `*` (argument unpacking) operator basically automates the process of expanding the list elements into individual arguments. `f(*args)` is equivalent to `f(args[0], args[1], args[2], ...)`" **is** exactly the reason why `*wP` works: it turns `wP` into two arguments. `wP` does not work because it is one argument. You need two arguments. I don't know how this could possibly be made any clearer.

Comment: In an earlier version of the code, I had used `wP` in the same way, but with a `Polygon` (with 3 points - a triangle), and it worked. So I didn't know why it didn't work when I made it two points and put it into a `Rectangle` as opposed to a `Polygon`.

Comment: Presumably `Polygon` takes a single list as a parameter, since the number of points in that case is variable, whereas since `Rectangle` always takes exactly two points, the class authors thought it would be a better design decision to make it take the individual points as arguments. This is the sort of thing you should be looking up in the documentation (or the source code) of the classes you're using.